# What is Android app's default value for Restrict background data?

Tags: android, android-source, application-settings, android-settings

Guys been trying to find some documentation about the **Background Data** value for an **Android** app.

- 1.What is the default value of an app after install?
- 2.Can you set the default value to true?
- 3.Can other apps (maybe system or third party e.g. data saver) affect its value?

From what I have experienced a client reported that one of my app's background data process is not working. I was able to check the phone physically and saw that the background data was disabled. The client said she didn't change anything in the background data settings of the app and OS is below Android N.

**for question #3** Android N's **Data Saver** can change the value but the client's OS was below Android N which is a bit suspicious.

Sample screenshot of the setting below:

[image: Sample screenshot of the setting]

Comment: Hi, if I have not misunderstood you, that you want to do is modify the value of using data from an external application

Comment: hello @VíctorSantoja, no I don't want to change the **background data enable** setting from an external app. I want to know the official details of an app's background data (see my questions in the description above). I haven't seen any confirmation or documentation about it. Lastly what I want to do is if **my app** finds that it is **disabled**, the goal is to redirect the user to the settings page to let him enable the setting. Thanks!